# How to handle overlapping pages in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, overlapping

[image]Hi i have extJS based UI. I am facing issues with overlapping pages.
For e.g: I have a page which has button which will open a panel kind of thing(Note: its not a seperate frame nor a seperate window. it opens up inside the same DOM as in the parent pages DOM). The panel overlaps the underlying page. the panel has a z-index in it style attribute. Now i wish to identify controls on this panels. how can i do it in selenium webdriver. Also the chances are that the panel and the underlying page may have same controls (but underlying controls are not active). so how can we identify such controls?
TIA.
Hi i want to add the screen shot of the UI but i am not able to add as it says that i need at least 10 reputation to post images. how can i get 10 reputations?
Also there are some controls which appear on both pages i.e the overlapped as well as overlapping page. And as its a extJS based UI the ids are getting auto-generated, CSSLocator will identify both the controls which appear on the UI and are similar. So i guess i am left with only one option of somehow hopping into the panel and then identifying the control. I tried using driver.switchTo.activeElement assuming that the underlying control is inactive but it is still not helping me. Any help in this regards. TIA

Attached the Screenshot. Now As you can see i have the highlighted panel overlapping the underlying page and it is present in the DOM of the overlapped page too.
Some pointers : 1) I tried with the XPath but this won't help as i will have to hardcode the xpath for every such control in UI(i am trying to generate dynamically xpath but it is still underway.)
2) Is there anyway that we can tell driver to select the control which has focus and is active.
The DOM source is too huge to be pasted.
The problematic control in question is the Start query button as seen in the screen shot which is present in twice and can appear multiple times in a page.
I am working on your suggested solutions.

Comment: can you share html code of your page or the webpage link, so that we can help you?

Comment: You can use xpath in this case. Try to add your webpage screenshot now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As only few lines of DOM are shown in the screenshot, so I can only take a guess on that you have.

I assume you have the DOM similar to this:

```
<button id='ext-gen343'>Start query</button>
<div id="ext-gen1829" class=" x-window" style="width: 30px; height: 85px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: visible; display: block;">
    <button id='ext-gen1920'>Start query</button>
</div>
```

Locate the window first then just find the button inside using cssSelector or Xpath.

```java
// Note that I used 'display: block;' to ensure we are looking for the active/visible window.
WebElement btnStartQueryInside = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'x-window') and contains(@style, 'display: block;')]//button[text()='Start query']"));
```

For your point #2, `driver.switchTo.activeElement` is the one you want, which you have mentioned before. But it is not an elegant solution to do this, or even won't work at all.